# Fslint unable to access directory

Tags: permissions, mount, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04.  New installation.  Installed FSlint from snap

Want to search for duplicate files on second hard disc mounted at /media/Disc2/Directory

1. I open Fslint to set path to directory.
2. Choose File System from list.   Media shows in list in RH panel
3. Select Media in RH panel
4. Message appears:  Could not read the contents of media : Permission denied

Accessing other directories doesn't seen to be a problem.
Fslint working fine on another computer running same software.

Any suggestions or help please?      Thanks.

Comment: In order to see files you as as the logined in user can not see start the command with sudo. Try in a terminal sudo fslint assuming that is the actual name of the app.

Comment: Doesn't work sadly.. FSlint runs from a GUI.  Thanks anyway..

Comment: All apps can be started from the terminal and if they are GUI it will launch the GUI.

Comment: @David not in this case. Perhaps because (at least in my case) the FSLint is a snap package, and when I run from a root environment, all sorts of bad things come up, varies - even once a dreaded "core" - also python errors, etc. I can confirm same issue. Tried installing a "non-snap" fsLint - still on it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and this command solved it:

```
sudo snap connect fslint-unofficial:removable-media
```

([Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437185&p=13933525#post13933525) )

Answer (score 0):

So FYI. after being extremely hopeful that the answer from Meszaros would work (sudo snap connect fslint-unofficial:removeable-media) and getting errors or "nothing" still. dropping the sudo, getting false hope and still fail.  searching all over the web. switching to "sudo snap interfaces fslint-unofficial:removeable-media", finding out 'interfaces' is deprecated. Trying the CLI suggested "connections" instead. trying several other replacements for "removeable-media", seeing tons and tons of other forum posts of all types for all sorts of snap packages failing to access USB media or privelaged folders ... 30 minutes later... and mind you this is a *brand new* ubuntu install i had dual-boot created and ignored for a few months after making.
THE ANSWER TURNED OUT TO BE:
***UPDATE YOUR DANG OS***
so sudo apt update or apt-get update or software-manager or software solutions any one of those (or probably half dozen others) but either way, update your dang linux install.  problem solved. no need to sudo, no need to try to run from root, none of which will work anyway.  just UPDATE YOUR OS!
lolllllllllllllllllllllllllllll